# Setting up Stat-ET Sweave for the first time

Tags: eclipse, r, sweave, statet

I've been following the [Getting started with Sweave](http://www.r-bloggers.com/getting-started-with-sweave-r-latex-eclipse-statet-texlipse/) guide and created a new project folder called MISC with a subfolder called Sweave.

I've placed my sample .Rnw file in this folder together with a copy of the Sweave.sty file.
I then changed my R working directory to MISC\Sweave.
Sweave does create the TEX file without problems, but then complains:

**Project output file format not set in project**

I've checked the project properties and I can't quite work out where I should set it. Any ideas?

P.S.: Does this mean that I will have to set this up for every single project I want to Sweave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your .tex file is located in a folder within your project folder, you will have to add the directory/folder name to your specified .tex and .pdf filenames.

1. Under the `Project Properties > Latex Project Properties` for your 'MISC' project folder, the first text box, Main TeX File, should be something like '/Sweave/myfile.tex' where 'myfile.tex' is the name of your Sweave document with the .tex extension.
2. The directory path should also be added to the name of your Output File in the second textbox: e.x. '/Sweave/myfile.pdf'.

To answer your P.S., if every project is in a separate project folder, you will have to set this up for every project since you have to specify single main .tex and output files.

Comment: I guess that's my problem - I don't have `Latex Project Properties` as a choice.

Comment: @JoanneDemmler The project properties depend on the type of project folder you used to create MISC.  The first thing to do is to make sure you have the Texlipse plugin installed if you don't have it already.  From here, you would create a new "LaTeX project" under the Texlipse folder instead of a "Project" under the "General" folder. Although it prompts you for names of the input and output .tex and pdf files, these can always be changed in the project properties later.

Comment: Ah! That is a bit disappointing, so I can't keep the `sweave` files together with the main project files (documentation, R scipts, sql scripts)?

Comment: I don't see why not, but it takes a bit of planning.  I guess that really depends on what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to Sweave multiple files in multiple projects from one R script resulting in multiple pdfs, or have everything resulting in one pdf? I think the easiest thing to to is to set up a R script which acts as a control script where you can Sweave and then convert the .tex files into pdfs. Ex `setwd("dir1")
Sweave("file1.Rnw")
texi2dvi(file="file1.tex", pdf = TRUE)`

Comment: @JoanneDemmler We can continue this conversation, if you like, regarding details of your setup via pm since it may not be of interest to the entire community.

Comment: I was just wondering, because I'm working on a lot of different projects, which would to some extend need their own `sweave` documents. So this might be multiple files for the same project (reports & publications). Especially as I might want to share documents over SVN and the other person will only have access to a specific project folder.

Comment: @JoanneDemmler: The only things I can think to add are 1) Make sure your R working directory, the location of your Sweave files, and the .tex output file are all in the same directory.2) Make sure your directory path and file names have no spaces in them, and if this fails, perhaps converting the Tex files to pdf using an external program such as TeXShop or changing some of the code to use knitr might work?

Comment: I will try knitr as soon as our system gets upgraded. I think some of the environment variables have gone missing and cause chaos.

Comment: The easiest solution, that enables me to keep the files in project folders and back them up over SVN seems to be to use LyX with sweave or knitr.